# jinja2 template for updating values based on condition

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a `test.j2` template file which has this line:

```
listener={{ protocol }}://localhost:9094
```

and `vars.yml` file to handle the variables

```yaml
---
sasl:
  enabled: true
  realm:
    admin_server: test.dev.com
ssl:
  enabled: true
  pwd: PASS
protocol: >
  {% if sasl.enabled or ssl.enabled %}
  SASL_SSL
  {% else %}
  PLAIN_TEXT
  {% endif %}
```

Now I want to update the j2 file like this:
If `sasl.anabled` and `ssl.enabled` are `true`

```
listener=sasl_ssl://localhost:9094,ssl://loclhost:9093
```

or if only `ssl.enabled` is `true`

```
listener=ssl://localhost:9093
```

and otherwise

```
listener=PLAIN_TEXT://localhost:9094
```

Note: I am only allowed to change conditions in `vars.yml` file.
How can meet conditions and update `test.j2`?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you are not allowed to change `test.j2`, which is a shame, as that is actually the place to do that. Just for the record, this is what you should have in your `test.j2` and you should ditch your `protocol` variable:

```
{% if sasl.enabled and ssl.enabled %}
listener=sasl_ssl://localhost:9094,ssl://loclhost:9093
{% elif (not sasl.enabled) and ssl.enabled %}
listener=ssl://loclhost:9093
{% else $}
listener=PLAIN_TEXT://loclhost:9094
{% endif %}
```

If you want to do that in your `vars.yaml`, you need to put everything in your `protocol` variable in case both `ssl` and `sasl` are enabled, witch is kind of hacky:

```yaml
protocol: >
  {% if sasl.enabled and ssl.enabled %}
  sasl_ssl://localhost:9094,ssl
  {% elif (not sasl.enabled) and ssl.enabled %}
  ssl
  {% else %}
  PLAIN_TEXT
  {% endif %}
```